# Where do you add iphone frameworks from

Tags: iphone

I want to add the MessageUI Framework to my project.

The first time I did it, I selected

```
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework
```

After I did that my project would no longer build - lots of syntax errors, and wouldn't build even after I told Xcode to delete the framework - still had syntax errors, just not quite as many.

So I went back to a back up of the project I'd made just before doing the add - thank goodness I had one - and tried again.  This time I selected the MessageUI framework from

```
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
```

Now the project builds fine.

I also noticed there was a MessageUI framework in the folder

```
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
```

Why would I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.1 one is the latest development kit for iPhone OS 3.1 that has to be supported for a submission to the App Store. Anything built using the 3.0 framework may possibly not (but more than likely will) be compatible with iPhone OS 3.1.